# How to find all matches by collection attribute using spring data jpa?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have got a collection attribute of an entity. I need to find in database all records that contains this string. Like a full matching "LIKE(%KEYWORD%)";

```
Page<Article> findByCategoryIdsContains(String categoryId, Pageable pageable);
```

But I got this error below:

```
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
unknown collection expression type[org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.SingularAttributePath]
```

I have tried different ways.

This code work fine：

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM cms_article WHERE category_ids LIKE %?1%", nativeQuery = true)
Page<Article> findByCategoryIdsLike(String categoryId, Pageable pageable);
```

But this code throw the error:

```java
Page<Article> findByCategoryIdsContains(String categoryId, Pageable pageable);
```

What is the correctly keyword query method?

Here is code for example:

Base entity:

```java
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Transient
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(columnDefinition = "char(24) comment 'Primary key ID'")
    protected String id;

    @CreatedDate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created_time", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "timestamp default current_timestamp comment 'Creation time'")
    protected Date createdTime;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "last_modified_time", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "timestamp default current_timestamp comment 'Last updateed time'")
    protected Date lastModifiedTime;

}
```

Article entity:

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "cms_article")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Table(appliesTo = "cms_article", comment = "Article information table")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Article extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(120) comment 'Article title'")
    private String title;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(24) comment 'Article author'")
    private String author;

    @Convert(converter = JpaJsonConverter.class)
    @Column(name = "cover_urls", columnDefinition = "varchar(255) comment 'Article covers'")
    private List<String> coverUrls;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "mediumtext comment 'Article content'")
    private String content;

    @Convert(converter = JpaJsonConverter.class)
    @Column(name = "category_ids", columnDefinition = "varchar(255) comment 'Article category ids'")
    private List<String> categoryIds;
}
```

My custom attribute converter for object to json string:

```java
public class JpaJsonConverter implements AttributeConverter<Object, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Object object) {
        return JSON.toJSONString(object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        return JSON.parse(dbData);
    }

}
```

The JPA Repository:

```java
public interface ArticleRepository extends JpaRepository<Article, String> {

    /**
     * Get article page by category id.
     *
     * @param categoryId category id
     * @param pageable   page information
     * @return Article page
     */
    Page<Article> findByCategoryIdsContains(String categoryId, Pageable pageable);

    /**
     * Get article page by category id.
     *
     * @param categoryId category id
     * @param pageable   page information
     * @return Article page
     */
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM cms_article WHERE category_ids LIKE %?1%", nativeQuery = true)
    Page<Article> findByCategoryIdsLike(String categoryId, Pageable pageable);

}
```

Here is database records：
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try findByCategoryContainingIgnoreCase method instead of findByCategoryIdsLike

```
@Query("Select cmsa from cms_article cmsa where cmsa.category_ids LIKE  %?1%")
Page<Article> findByCategoryContainingIgnoreCase(String categoryId);
```

for without @Query try below.

```
Page<Article> findByCategoryIgnoreCaseContaining(String categoryId);
```

Comment: Your first way can't get correct records, and second way still got same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
Page<Article> findByCategoryIdsContainingIgnoreCase(String categoryId, Pageable p);
```

Maybe consider not having Ids put into the database this way. You could have a seperate table matching `categoryId` to the `articleId`. Then you would have a row for each category belonging to an article.

i.e.:

```
articleId | categoryId
    1     |     1
    1     |     2    
    2     |     1
    2     |     3
```

Comment: I still got this error：`unknown collection expression type[org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.SingularAttributePath]`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one**

```
Page<Article> findByCategoryContaining(String categoryId);
```

**Referred Document**
[click](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/)

Check the content in above mentioned document

Table 3. Supported keywords inside method names